# Получение значения свойства кнопки из стиля

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

Есть стиль для кнопки:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF0DFFAA" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Stroke="#FF1E0CE8" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="2,1"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,4.5,0,2.5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sample Text" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="96" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

В нем есть `TextBlock`, в котором есть текст. Как брать значение свойства `Content` самой кнопки, а не стиля, ведь для каждой кнопки стиль писать - чересчур?

Comment: Для этого надо задать в стиле `<ContentPresenter />` (вроде он).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если взялись за WPF, то про привязку данных нужно знать от и до.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF0DFFAA" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Stroke="#FF1E0CE8" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="2,1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,4.5,0,2.5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="96" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```